# It is possible to recover the src from a deployed .WAR file?

Tags: war, aop, aspectj, decompiler, jd-gui

I am working with a lot of legacy applications here. One of them (deployed in production) need to be edited because doesn't have any log.

I decompiled the it, but I have no idea about how to reassemble in this situation. I could not even recompile de single classes edited because of the compiler optimization.

(I am using Java 6)

Sorry if my english is bad, I am just a junior

Comment: No, not in the general case.  Normally War files only contain compiled bytecode (binary) files, the source is not available.  Ask the authors and they may be able to supply the source to you.

Comment: I agree with @markspace -- I might soften the statement to 'not practical and not at all easy' rather than saying it's entirely not possible, but what you need to do is probably an order of magnitude harder than rewriting the service from scratch using something like spring-boot and spring-data.

Comment: Hello everybody. We did a turnaround plan using aspect.You guys think it's okay for me to describe it better in this question? @EngineerDollery

Comment: Is it an answer? I'd write it up as an answer if it is. It's ok to answer your own questions -- if you're the only one with the right answer then it is encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

No. A WAR file is just a specialized JAR file that contains, in addition to the compiled bytecode, JSP files, static HTML files, and a descriptor file that tells the webserver how to deploy the app. What it does not contain is the original source code. This means your only options are working with the decompiled code, or asking the original developers for the source code.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, compilation and decompilation are lossy processes, so you cannot in general recompile decompiled code, and even if it does compile, it may not be identical to the original binary.

One alternative is to use [Krakatau disassembler and assembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau). Krakatau can roundtrip Java bytecode to a human readable text format, which makes it easy to edit bytecode losslessly. The main downside is that you have to have a good understanding of Java bytecode to understand the disassembly and it is a lot harder to read or edit than Java source code.